# RestKit POST Error With Asymmetric Keys

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, restkit

I'm having an issue posting objects to my server using RestKit. I'm using last night's version of RestKit but it's been an issue since at least last year. What I'm doing is that I'm attempting to save a new object to the server but when I do, I receive a mapping error before the request is ever sent to the server. The problem is that my JSON response keys and my NSObject attributes are asymmetric even though that RestKit documentation says that they don't have to be. Previous to adding the new POST command my GET command for downloading the JSON response was just fine. RestKit had no problem with the asymmetric key mapping and everying worked. However, now that I'm attempting to POST the NSObject back to the server, I am receiving NSUknownKeyException errors. If I change the keys to be symmetric, RKObjectMappingOperation completes and the POST will actually be sent to the server. This seems like a bug to me but I wanted to make sure that this wasn't requirement for posting.

Here are my code details. Here is the mapping:

```
RKObjectMapping* restaurantReviewMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RestaurantReview class] ];
[restaurantReviewMapping mapKeyPath:@"restaurant_id" toAttribute:@"restaurantId"];
[restaurantReviewMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"];
[restaurantReviewMapping mapKeyPath:@"review" toAttribute:@"review"];
```

Here is the NSObject:

```
@interface RestaurantReview : NSObject

  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* restaurantId;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* rating;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* title;

@end
```

Post Command that was copied from the object mapping documentation:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] sendObject:review toResourcePath:fullRestaurantReviewUrl usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.serializationMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[RestaurantReview class] ];
}];
```

And finally, the error that I receive before the request is ever sent to the server:

```
2012-08-23 14:57:49.118 [61331:c07] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:374 POST or PUT request for source object <RestaurantReview: 0x74d55c0>, serializing to MIME Type application/json for transport...
2012-08-23 14:57:49.119 [61331:c07] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMappingOperation.m:655 Starting mapping operation...
2012-08-23 14:57:49.184 [61331:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RestaurantReview 0x74d55c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key restaurant_id.'
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How do you add restaurantReviewMapping to the mapping provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to provide the `inverseMapping` for `serializationMapping`.

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that. I completely missed the part about storing a serialized mapping on the ObjectManager. I was only storing the regular mapping.